# How to avoid callback hell when dealing with multiple nested repository calls which rely on previous repo's return value

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I save a record to a table. Once saved, I need to check another table if a record exists. If record exists, I need to get it from the second table and update it and save it again, if it doesn't exist, I need to save a new record.

Here is how I am doing this right now, but it is messy. Is there a better way to write this? I tried using `Mono.block()`, but it doesn't work and isn't how I want to write.

```
Mono<EntityDir> savedDirMono = dirRepo.save(dir); //Save in db

    //We need to check if the newly saved entityDir needs to be saved to another Table known as Connector, This is done inside this flatmap chain
    return savedDirMono.flatMap(

            savedDir -> {

                //We need to add savedDir to Connector if this is true
                if ((savedDir.getParent() == null || savedDir.getParent().isEmpty())) {

                    //Check if a record already exists with same userID, if yes then we need to get it from table and update it's values and then AGAIN save it to connector table
                    return connectorUserToDirRepo
                            .findById(savedDir.getCreatorID())
                            .defaultIfEmpty(new EntityConnectorUserToDir(null, null))
                            .flatMap(savedConnector -> {

                                //If this is true then no record found so we can simply save new record
                                if (savedConnector.getUserID() == null || savedConnector.getUserID().isEmpty()) {

                                    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
                                    stringList.add(savedDir.get_id());

                                    //Save to other db and flatmap it and return it to upper part of the nest
                                    return connectorUserToDirRepo.save(new EntityConnectorUserToDir(savedDir.getCreatorID(), stringList))
                                            .map(connectorUserToDir -> savedDir);
                                } else {


                                    //Record exists we need to update it's dir list and then save it again
                                    List<String> stringList = savedConnector.getDirs();
                                    stringList.add(savedDir.get_id());

                                    //Save to connector db, flatmap it and return it to upper part of nest
                                    return connectorUserToDirRepo.save(savedConnector)
                                            .map(connectorUserToDir -> savedDir);
                                }

                            });
                } else {

                    //not a parent so no need to do further
                    log.info("NOT A PARENT");
                    return Mono.justOrEmpty(savedDir);
                }

            }
    );
```

Comment: have you tried using functions? they are free

Comment: Use the database... Instead of doing this in code, use your database to do this, write an UPSERT statement instead of doing this in code. So just insert, then do an upsert for your second part. That way your code is only 2 calls and the rest is done by your database.